# How to create a set vlan flow?

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I want to do the equivalent of the following :

```
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 table=2,metadata=1379878762,actions=push_vlan:0x8100,mod_vlan_vid:4000,output:6,goto_table:4 -O openflow13
```

How can I do this in opendaylight java code? I tried based on some examples I could find,  but no flows appeared or sometimes with enough tweaking I could get a part of the flow to appear (I could never see the output action). I am using Carbon (the latest version of carbon) for my development. Is it worth switching to the nightly snapshot?

When I do this with opendaylight, I find that any actions having to do with vlan do not appear in my flow.  Only the goto appears in the flow.

=== UPDATE ===

I use the following java code to set and create the vlan tag (suggested by answer below):

```
    private static Instruction createSetVlanAndOutputToPortInstructions( int vlanId,
        String outputPortUri) {

    List<Action> actionList = new ArrayList<>();
    ActionBuilder ab = new ActionBuilder();

    Integer VLAN_ETHERTYPE = 0x8100;
    ActionBuilder actionBuilder = new ActionBuilder();

    //push vlan
    Action pushVlanAction = actionBuilder
        .setOrder(0).setAction(new PushVlanActionCaseBuilder()
            .setPushVlanAction(new PushVlanActionBuilder()
                .setEthernetType(VLAN_ETHERTYPE)
                    .build())
                    .build())
                .build();
    actionList.add(pushVlanAction);

    //set vlan id

    SetVlanIdActionBuilder tab = new SetVlanIdActionBuilder();
    tab.setVlanId(new VlanId((int) vlanId));
    SetVlanIdActionCaseBuilder vidcb = new SetVlanIdActionCaseBuilder();
    vidcb.setSetVlanIdAction(tab.build());
    Action setVlanIdAction = actionBuilder.setOrder(1).setAction(vidcb.build()).build();



    OutputActionBuilder output = new OutputActionBuilder();
    output.setMaxLength(Integer.valueOf(0xffff));

    Uri controllerPort = new Uri(outputPortUri);
    output.setOutputNodeConnector(controllerPort);

    ab = new ActionBuilder();
    ab.setKey(new ActionKey(0));
    ab.setAction(new OutputActionCaseBuilder().setOutputAction(output.build()).build());
    ab.setOrder(2);
    actionList.add(ab.build());

    ApplyActionsBuilder aab = new ApplyActionsBuilder();

    aab.setAction(actionList);

    InstructionBuilder ib = new InstructionBuilder();
    ib.setKey(new InstructionKey(0));
    ib.setInstruction(new ApplyActionsCaseBuilder().setApplyActions(aab.build()).build());

    return ib.build();
}
```

The code that creates a flow rule is here:

```
 FlowBuilder tagPacketFlow = new FlowBuilder().setTableId((short) tableId)
            .setFlowName("metadataMatchSetVlanTagSendToPortAndGoToStripVlanTagTable").setId(flowId)
            .setKey(new FlowKey(flowId)).setCookie(flowCookie);
    MatchBuilder matchBuilder = new MatchBuilder();
    createMetadataMatch(matchBuilder, flowCookie.getValue());

    InstructionBuilder ib = new InstructionBuilder();
    Instruction createVlanTag = FlowUtils.createSetVlanAndOutputToPortInstructions(
            SdnMudConstants.MUD_RULE_HIT_LABEL, outputPortUri);

    InstructionsBuilder insb = new InstructionsBuilder();
    ArrayList<Instruction> instructions = new ArrayList<Instruction>();
    instructions.add(createVlanTag);
    Instruction gotoInstruction = ib.setInstruction(new GoToTableCaseBuilder()
            .setGoToTable(new GoToTableBuilder().setTableId(SdnMudConstants.STRIP_VLAN_RULE_TABLE).build()).build())
            .setOrder(3)
            .setKey(new InstructionKey(0)).build();
    instructions.add(gotoInstruction);

    insb.setInstruction(instructions);
    tagPacketFlow.setMatch(matchBuilder.build()).setInstructions(insb.build())
            .setPriority(35).setBufferId(OFConstants.ANY)
            .setHardTimeout(time).setIdleTimeout(0).setFlags(new FlowModFlags(false, false, false, false, false));
```

Upon invoking the code I see this in openvswitch:

```
 cookie=0x523f476a, duration=0.012s, table=2, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, hard_timeout=30000, priority=35,metadata=0x523f476a actions=goto_table:3
```

And here's the dump from the config datastore corresponding to this flow:

```
    {
                        "buffer_id": 4294967295,
                        "cookie": 1379878762,
                        "flags": "",
                        "flow-name": "metadataMatchSetVlanTagSendToPortAndGoToStripVlanTagTable",
                        "hard-timeout": 30000,
                        "id": "toaster.nist.gov/42",
                        "idle-timeout": 0,
                        "instructions": {
                            "instruction": [
                                {
                                    "go-to-table": {
                                        "table_id": 3
                                    },
                                    "order": 0
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "match": {
                            "metadata": {
                                "metadata": 1379878762
                            }
                        },
                        "priority": 35,
                        "table_id": 2
                    }
```

So the Vlan Setting just disappeared.

==== End UPDATE ====

==== UPDATE 1 ====

I logged the flow before committing the transaction. Here's the set VLAN instruction :

```
   ApplyActionsCase [_applyActions=ApplyActions 
      [_action=[Action [_action=PushVlanActionCase 
      [_pushVlanAction=PushVlanAction [_ethernetType=33024,
      _vlanId=VlanId [_value=1001], augmentation=[]], augmentation=[]], 
     _key=ActionKey [_order=0], _order=0, augmentation=[]], 
      Action [_action=SetVlanIdActionCase[_setVlanIdAction=SetVlanIdAction
     [_vlanId=VlanId [_value=1001], augmentation=[]], 
     augmentation=[]], _key=ActionKey [_order=1], _order=1, 
     augmentation=[]], Action [_action=OutputActionCase 
     [_outputAction=OutputAction [_maxLength=65535,
     _outputNodeConnector=Uri [_value=openflow:1:6], 
      augmentation=[]], augmentation=[]], 
     _key=ActionKey [_order=2], _order=2,
      augmentation=[]]], augmentation=[]], augmentation=[]]
```

I can't see anything wrong with it.

=== End UPDATE 1 ===

=== Update 2 ===

When I remove the goto and follow the pattern of the xml here:
https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Editing_OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin:End_to_End_Flows:Example_Flows#Push_VLAN

it only works WITHOUT the goto. In other words if I remove the goto I can see the push flow in the config datastore. If I put the goto in, ONLY the goto appears.

==== End Update 2 ====

I see an issue in the issue tracker about vlan flows in opendaylight soutbound being broken but it appears to have been fixed in 2014 (?).

Is this fixed in nitrogen and how can I go about filing a bug against opendaylight?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Integer VLAN_ETHERTYPE = 0x8100;
ActionBuilder actionBuilder = new ActionBuilder();
List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();

//push vlan
Action pushVlanAction = actionBuilder
    .setOrder(0).setAction(new PushVlanActionCaseBuilder()
        .setPushVlanAction(new PushVlanActionBuilder()
            .setEthernetType(VLAN_ETHERTYPE)
                .build())
                .build())
            .build();
actions.add(pushVlanAction);

//set vlan id
Action setVlanIdAction = actionBuilder
    .setOrder(1).setAction(new SetFieldCaseBuilder()
        .setSetField(new SetFieldBuilder()
            .setVlanMatch(new VlanMatchBuilder()
                .setVlanId(new VlanIdBuilder()
                    .setVlanId(new VlanId(vlanID))
                     .setVlanIdPresent(true)
                .build())
            .build())
        .build())
    .build())
    .build();
actions.add(setVlanIdAction);
```

Then, you need to add your actions into your instructions in the following way:

```
//ApplyActions
ApplyActions applyActions = new ApplyActionsBuilder().setAction(actions).build();

//Instruction
Instruction applyActionsInstruction = new InstructionBuilder() 
        .setOrder(0).setInstruction(new ApplyActionsCaseBuilder()
                .setApplyActions(applyActions) 
                .build()) 
            .build();
```

Also take a look [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.action.types.rev131112.action.action.PushVlanActionCaseBuilder).

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. My table still has:  cookie=0x523f476a, duration=0.012s, table=2, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, hard_timeout=30000, priority=35,metadata=0x523f476a actions=goto_table:3 .

Comment: Why does setField equire a VlanMatchBuilder() ? I am confused about the programming model.

Comment: @LostInTheFrequencyDomain I think you did not add the Vlan actions correctly in your instructions... See my edited post on how to add them. As for your second question, I am not aware either, I found it like this in a tutorial.

Comment: @LostInTheFrequencyDomain actually I found another example, see my edited post.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work (had tried it earlier). I am turning on logging for the transaction manager to see if I can find something. Huge amounts of logs.

Comment: I removed the VlanMatchBuilder() it did not change the constructed instruction. Still no luck.

Comment: There was (I believe) a bug in Carbon which was causing the behavior above. I am able to create such flows after upgrading my code to Nitrogen. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Nitrogen, I found that my problem goes away. So there appears to have been a bug in the Carbon release. Not sure when it got fixed.